# Over-eager duplicate checking

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

Stack Overflow is not just a wiki. It is a discursive learning platform.

Over-eager duplicate checking and the resultant rapid closing of questions harms this latter use case for Stack Overflow.

Oftentimes duplicates are not exact duplicates, but closely related to existing questions. These kind of questions can offer a first step on the ladder for contributors to answer "easy" questions within their knowledge domain.

Letting people answer these questions delivers a better learning experience for both the questioner (they get a tailored response), and the answerer (they consolidate their knowledge by putting it in an answer).

Furthermore, oftentimes the users posing these kinds of question are completely new to Stack Overflow. A more helpful first impression will make them more likely to stick around and contribute when they are more knowledgeable.

Please can we be more forgiving of duplicates and near-duplicates?

Note I am NOT saying duplicate checking should be removed altogether. I am saying it we should be more forgiving.

Existing, related questions can, of course, continue to be linked from these questions.

Comment: Can you provide an example or two of questions that would be better no to close? In my experience, most of these cases can easily be solved with a couple comments.

Comment: So, you're saying, wait for x months/years until we close a question as a duplicate?

Comment: No. I'm saying accept that near-duplicates are a reality that cannot be avoided, and that there would be positive side effects to a less strict approach to them - and that there are negative side effects to strict closing of them.

Comment: @Ben I can accept the former (near-dupes can't be avoided), however I see no positive side effects to being less strict with them, nor negative effects of being strict with them

Comment: My understanding is that we had duplicates so that experts didn't have to continuously answer the same questions, and so that new users could find better answers to their questions. What's the exact benefit here? We're hand-holding more, moving away from "we're building for the future", and.... gaining what exactly?

Comment: This question could really do with some examples of cases that would be better off answered than closed, as Yivi asked.

Comment: I think this question can be tackled in the abstract - the question is about near-duplicates or questions that could be boiled down to an existing question. If I linked to a specific question, I worry that discussion would dive into the rabbit hole of the rights and wrongs of that particular question. Note: I am NOT saying duplicate checking should be removed. I am saying that it should be relaxed.

Comment: @patrice If an expert user wants to avoid expending effort on the near-duplicate, then a comment with a link to the dupe will suffice. The question is then open for people to contribute to solve the questioner's particular version of the problem.

Comment: @Ben: The problem here is that the suggestion isn't that strong without an example that illustrates why it's an good idea... As it is right now, it's too vague.

Comment: @Ben but then we lose the main power of duplication. You'll *always* have someone who wants more precious unicorn points and try to spin that "this near duplicate should stay open so I can get better, more tailored answers to my question!" And then, with enough dillution of our good content between many duplicates... we become "just another Q&A site." As for the "I wanna discuss in the abstract". Well in the abstract, me (and I think a good chunk of the community) thinks duplicate works fine as it is. So.... In the abstract, I don't see a big incentive to change it :/

Comment: I'm opening a discussion. I frequently see novice developers with a rep of seven (or whatever) presenting with an honest question (often a problem from their place of work), for which a tailored answer would help (because of their inexperience) and they are met with their question being downvoted and closed within minutes. I just think there has to be a more positive approach. Given that dupes are a current and future inevitability, why not accept that and simply link to the dupe, but leave it open for the unicorn points for novices to cut their teeth.

Comment: Yea, but it's not like this discussion hasn't been started time and time again. Usually without compelling evidence or reasoning why: _"why not accept that <...>"_ Why should we?

Comment: Maybe there is an issue then?

Comment: @Cerbrus I have supplied, in this q and the discussion the rational reason for the opening of the discussion and for a change. To restate: dupes exist. They are an inevitability. At the moment near dupes - usually from novice users - are relentlessly closed. Linking to the dupe is important, but why not leave them open for other (usually novice) contributors to gather the unicorn points as a step on the ladder to more expert contribution.

Comment: Not really. Nothing new, and nothing that outweighs consolidating knowledge in canonicals... Just because an idea gets suggested multiple times doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Linking to a canonical is important. And that can be done _at the same time as_ permitting solutions to the precise problem of the user.

Comment: exact duplicates never exist. the purpose of duplicate is to link to a closely related question. We don't close the question because it's the same BUT because it's related and we can (after few effort of reading) find the solution to the closed question.

Comment: Linking to the related question is important. I am not proposing that stop. Exacxt duplicates do sometimes exist (eg "how do closures work in JS?"). For _exact_ duplicates, I am happy for closing to continue.

Comment: Then why is it important to answer the duplicate any way? The answer should be in the dupe target. If it's not, then either the dupe target needs an additional answer (a new approach?) or, the dupe target is a poor fit.

Comment: and how to identify an *exact* duplicate? All the questions I closed are *exact* duplicate from my perspective so I don't want them to be answered. How can we agree about the meaning of *exact*?

Comment: Sure. The answer is there. And the dupe should be linked to. And if it is an _exact_ dupe then the q can be closed. But for near-dupes leaving it open for a tailored answer can be helpful.

Comment: For near dupes the closure is usually enough. If that's not the case, a small comment giving the user a nudge in the right direction should be plenty.

Comment: This isn't "Semantics and rabbit holes". Your suggestion is vague, and has a couple of problems that we're trying to point out and explain.

Comment: Oftentimes these novice users can be helped even better by delivering them a tailored answer. The dupe should always be linked to if possible.

Comment: SO's mission is not to help the user. It's to help all future readers. Future readers aren't helped by 100 questions with 200 tailored answers with minor variations. Future readers are helped with good questions and good solutions that illustrate the problem and how to tackle it.

Comment: As long as the canonical is linked to, what's the problem?

Comment: The ___point___ of duplicate closure is to prevent similar answers appearing all over the place. Duplicate closure is a signpost saying _"this was asked before, find your answer here"_. Duplicate closure makes search machines find the right questions.

Comment: As long as the canonical is linked to, I don't see why it matters. It presents a useful stepping stone for inexperienced users to jump in an help and start their journey to becoming a more expert contributor, and the (usually novice) questioner gets a tailored response.

Comment: I'm not going to repeat myself, or I might as well close the comments as duplicates of one another.

Comment: Also, many duplicate questions tends to be localized in nature, hence it is only beneficial to the asker. Closing the question as duplicate at least lets the asker know where the solution is, even though it is not likely to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: "[Stack Overflow] is a discursive learning platform". I don't think so. Do you have any support for such claim?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec a while ago there was a (failed) [attempt to officially present it as a thing for learning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312859/165773)

Comment: I would submit that requiring a novice to read some 3rd party code and a good explanation of the problems with it and a solution to them, and then understanding that solution and applying it to their own code is a better learning experience than simply be handed the solution tailor-made for their own code. Of course it's *harder* and people might not like it because of that, but we're not here to make it as easy as possible for each individual person.

Answer (score 19):

The inherent danger in the approach you suggest, is that you end with endless variations of the same question.

Even now, since dupe closures are not dealt as quickly or relentlessly as you imply, this happens.

And the problem with that is that this is helpful **for the asker**. But it is detrimental **for the repository and all the future users that will consume the repository**.

Because by adding more and more variations of the same questions we are just adding *noise*, that makes it harder to find pearls among the sand.

The main discussion here is the same that we have every now and then: what's the site's objective? Conceptually, the original idea was to build a high quality, highly curated, low noise, repository of question and answers.

We do so by asking questions, and in the process we help the asker. Which is great, although secondary.

When the question is closed as a duplicate, we are still helping the asker, since we are pointing them to the right place to find a useful answer. Of course, one can always supply additional information in comments to help the asker bride the gap between *their* specific variation and the target dupe.

All in all, I do not think going in the direction you suggest is helpful. The signal/noise ratio would decrease even further.

Comment: This signal to noise risk can be mitigated by clearly linking the canonical at the top of the dupe. My point is: we might see an overall better outcome by leaving more questions open (while at the same time linking to the dupe).

Comment: No, that doesn't help. You still have more posts adding noise to the search results. A few signposts are good, a forest of signpost, not so great.

Comment: @Ben: Your suggestion results in increased noise by allowing answers on dupe-closed questions (but only on some of them, which is vague)...

Comment: Maybe simply permitting answers on all dupe-marked questions is the answer.

Comment: _How_ is that the answer? You keep on insisting it's "better" without explaining why, or addressing our issues with the suggestion.

Comment: @Ben then why having duplicate at all if the answer is already giving?

Comment: @cerberus Your "_how_" comment injects heat into the discussion that is unnecessary. I have explained "why" twice now. I'll do it a third time: enabling answers on near-dupes will deliver a better experience for novice users of the site by delivering them a tailored response (as well as pointing them to the canonical, of course). It will also provide a stepping stone for junior users to engage with simpler questions, starting them on the journey to being more important contributors. Each issue raised with the suggestion I have addressed, including the  data cleanliness one.

Comment: _"enabling answers on near-dupes will deliver a better experience for novice users of the site by delivering them a tailored response"_ And the problem there is that that's not the mission of SO. That's a problem we stated multiple times and you haven't addressed.

Comment: Sorry Ben, but you haven't. Again, even if the questions are linked you have a multitude of signposts, the forest I mentioned earlier. That's incredibly noisy and hard to maintain. The idea is to have a useful amount of dupes, variations that could make easier to find the answer if users are searching by different keywords. Not infinite variations that would choke any attempt of indexation, and would make curation even harder than it is.

Comment: @cerberus What is the mission of SO?

Comment: @Ben Build a high quality programming Q&A repository. I think I mention this in my answer above.

Comment: OK, in order to meet that mission you need engaged and enthusiastic contributors and you need questioners. If Joe Programmer with seven rep turns up, crafts a question as best he can and is immediately downvoted and has his question closed - do you think he will be more or less likely to use an alternative Q&A site, or return when he is a subject matter expert? Or what about the junior developers who no longer have much of an opportunity to contribute on the site - are they more or less likely to become expert contributors over time?

Comment: I do not think we have a question scarcity problem. But we do have a question quality problem.

Comment: Let me turn that around, @Ben: What do you think makes subject matter experts come to SO? Not having to wade through dozens of duplicates of the same null pointer reference and newbies that don't understand AJAX certainly helps.

Comment: My focus is on contributors. Novice contributors often start asking more questions than writing answers. But over time they become the contributors.

Comment: @Cerbrus Klout and the fact that teaching is often the best way to learn and stay on top of your subject matter.

Comment: The main issue is here again that we focus on "pushing *anyone* away from SO is bad" instead of focusing on what we should always focus on : our place as a repository of knowledge. Personally I go to stack cause, unlike other forums, I don't have to check 14 different questions and answer sets. I find one, and if it's not the one I need, there's usually a canonical. I then read the dupe, I extract the info I need, add it in my "programming knowledge", then I apply it. If I needed specifics, tailored answers... I'd go back to school to learn. Stack isn't a learning platform :/.

Comment: @Ben: Writing the same answer over and over again isn't exactly a good learning experience for the author.

Comment: You don't have to. Link to the dupe. Move on. If a novice wants to address the specific instance of the problem and win some unicorn points, let them go for it.

Comment: and then we teach everyone "it's ok to ask dupes, someone will come in and tailor *any* answer you want to your specific question. No need to learn programming or evolve your knowledge. Someone will always be there to regurgitate it for you". At this point... let's just drop question quality altogether

Comment: This is moving in circles, very rapidly. The same arguments are repeated, and I see no attempt to address several points that were raised.

Comment: I'd argue the benefits (mentioned elsewhere here) of permitting answers on dupes would outweigh that downside. The link to the canonical remains important, but we all ask dumb questions and reinvent the wheel when we are starting out. Meh. "let's drop question quality altogether" is a reductio ad absurdum fallacy.